# More complex charting in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've got data that looks something like this:

```
Campaign    Date       Clicks
EmailA      14/08/01   20
EmailB      14/08/01   10
EmailC      14/08/01   5
EmailA      14/08/02   15
EmailB      14/08/02   7
EmailC      14/08/02   3
EmailA      14/08/03   10
EmailB      14/08/03   5
EmailC      14/08/03   1
```

I'd like to be able to set up a Google Spreadsheet chart to draw a line for each campaign, with the clicks charted out over time.

However, I've got to do this with lots of data, so manually adjusting the data (besides changing sorting) isn't really an option. And I don't want to have to manually define data ranges.

Is this possible? I know Google Spreadsheets isn't as complex as Excel, but I'm hoping this is doable.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new table using [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?rd=1) (this will dynamically update as the source data changes):

`=QUERY(A:C,"select B, sum(C) where B is not null group by B pivot A",1)`

This pivots the data on the campaigns, and should facilitate charting the three series.